# "stdin is not a terminal" when run Laravel Envoy tasks

Tags: php, macos, laravel, ssh, laravel-envoy

One month later, all commands works great, but now...

When I try run  `envoy run deploy`

```
@servers([
    'mt' => 'user@xxxx.xxxx.xxxx'
])

@task('deploy', ['on' => 'mt'])
    cd /var/www/html/xxx.xxxxxx.xxxx
    git pull origin dev
    composer dump-autoload -o
    php artisan cache:clear
@endtask
```

I get this error:

```
git:(dev) ✗ envoy run deploy
[]: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
[]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname bash -s: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I put the content of my `id_rsa.pub` in the server `authorized_keys`, and the normal login works well, for example: `ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx` - I can login without a password.

So... what I'm doing wrong?

---

I'm using:

- php 5.6
- zsh + oh-my-zsh
- iTerm 2
- Yosemite

---

If you need more details, tell me after down vote please.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running the `envoy run deploy` command in an interactive shell, or via something else? eg: `ssh foo@bar envoy run deploy`?

Comment: directly. I'm using zsh + oh-my-zsh in iTerm 2.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution, but still I don't think that's it.

That's my code:

```
@servers([
    'mt' => 'user@xxxx.xxxx.xxxx'
])
```

Tha the solution:

```
@servers(['mt' => 'user@xxxx.xxxx.xxxx'])
```

The **server function** must be entire **inline**.

Thank's for you time guys!